# Call the base Constructor in the Constructor of the subclass

Tags: c#, oop, constructor

Is it possible to call the base Constructor at spicific point in the constructer of the subclass like:

```
public class SuperClass
{
  public SuperClass(Object myObject)
  {
     // init some values ...
  }
}

public class SubClass: SuperClass
{
  public SubClass(): base(Object myObject)
  {
     //Check some preconditions
     base(myObject);
     // Do some other stuff
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

One way to achieve this behavior you could extract the contents of the base constructor out into a method and then call that method from the subclass.

Another less closely tied method would be to just not use inheritance here.  It's possible that this is a situation in which composition would make more sense.  (It's impossible to say for sure without knowing more information though.)

Comment: I was expecting it to work, i think in delphi its possible which makes sense if you need to ensure some conditions depending on the context, ut avoid doble code in ssubclasses.

Answer (score 1):

No, because at `//Check some preconditions` you'd have a partially constructed object. This would lead to all sorts of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The right syntax is

```
public class SubClass: SuperClass
{
  public SubClass(object myObject): base(myObject)
  {

  }
}
```

[Here is link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of using constructors. It is impossible to call it in ctor's body directly.